# Image using uri as source not shown

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native App which downloads images from external sources and saves them into dedicated local cache folder. Later they get displayed in different views. The images are initially not available in the app bundle.

```
<Image source={{uri: uri}} resizeMode="contain" style={style} />
```

I use the URI format for the source input parameter of Image component referring a local folder. I pass width and height as style as well, in fact the image size is always known before drawing. It works fine on iOS but not on Android.

As the documentation says, I should use require('') for local images on Android. This works for static images but not for downloaded on run time.

Has anybody idea how could I solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
class CachedImage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        uri: null
    }

    async _handleCache(source) {        
        const path = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.CacheDir}${sha1(source.uri).toString()}.jpg`;        
        const exists = await RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(path);
        if (exists) {
            this.setState({uri: path});                
        } else {
            // encoding the file to preserve proper URL transmition
            await RNFetchBlob
                .config({path})
                .fetch("GET", source.uri, {});
            this.setState({uri: path});
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this._handleCache(this.props.source).done();
    }

    render() {
        const { style } = this.props;

        if (this.state.uri != null) {            
            return (                
                <Image source={{uri: this.state.uri}} resizeMode="contain" style={style} />
            );
        }
        return(
            <View style={style}/> //todo: display activity while loading ...
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<CachedImage
   style={{width: _width , height: _height}}
   source={{uri: 'http://...'}} />
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on Android. Both emulator and device - dev env. Have you found a fix or a cause?

Answer (score 1):

Import this packages

```
import { StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

Render image like this

```
<Image source={{uri: uri}} style={styles.image} />
```

Add this styles at the bottom

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2
    }
});
```

This should work if any issue write that down below!

Comment: There is no problem with the styling. The Image is properly sized on the screen. It just does not get displayed on Android. The same is working on iOS.

Comment: What is inside the uri variable just do a console.log and paste the returned data! The above code is tested in both ios and android

Comment: this.state.uri contains this in example: "/data/data/_package_/cache5e122ddefee010dbac4e97355d51b125d934aa70.jpg"

Comment: No I do not use Expo.